# Spring boot Whitelabel page error for unauthorized ldap group access

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

I'm developing a web application in spring boot 2.0.0 and spring security 5.0.6 and I've had perfect luck with it until I added some logic that validates that the user is part of an LDAP group.  If the user provides invalid credentials, the login page is shown again with a validation error displayed, but when the credentials are correct but the user is not part of the required LDAP group, the application is redirected to a Whitelabel Error Page that, along with that title in bold letters shows this:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Feb 22 18:40:55 EST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden
```

This is the correct error, so I know the authentication is working.  But I want to stay on the login page and not redirect, and I cannot figure out how to do that.

My entire configure method for my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is shown here below:

```
   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // Disabling CSRF because it causes issues with API requests (POSTs don't
      // contain the CSRF tokens).
      http.csrf().disable();

      http.headers().frameOptions().disable();

      http.authorizeRequests()

            // This line turns off authentication for all management endpoints, which means all
            // endpoints that start with "/actuator" (the default starter path for management endpoints
            // in spring boot applications).  To selectively choose which endpoints to exclude from authentication,
            // use the EndpointRequest.to(String ... method, as in the following example:
            // .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("beans", "info", "health", "jolokia")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).permitAll()

            // Do not authenticate resource requests
            .antMatchers(
                  "/app/css/**",
                  "/app/img/**",
                  "/app/js/**",
                  "/app/bootstrap/**").permitAll()

            .antMatchers(
                  "/admin/**",
                  "/app/builds/**",
                  "/app/monitor/**",
                  "/app/review/**")
               .hasRole(requiredRole)

            // All other requests are authenticated
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            // Any unauthenticated request is forwarded to the login page
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage(LOGIN_FORM)
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(successHandler())

            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint())

            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGOUT_FORM))
            .logoutSuccessUrl(LOGIN_FORM);
   }
```

I'm open to critique of the construct of this entire method, btw--I've taken over this project and this is new to me.  This code was working perfectly before I introduced the 6 lines ending with .hasRole(requiredRole), and it still works as long as the user is part of the required group.

I haven't provided the source for some of the methods that are called here, and I'm happy to paste them if someone would like.  I'm guessing someone that knows this stuff well will spot the problem right away.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I landed upon is similar to those I've found by googling around.  I created an error controller that resolves to /error.  At first I didn't think my error handler was ever being reached because I wasn't properly configured in my editor to debug a spring boot application, but I resolved that this morning.  I added an error controller that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {
   private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

   @Autowired
   private ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;

   @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
   public String error(WebRequest request, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
      Map<String, Object> attrs = this.errorAttributes.getErrorAttributes(request, false);

      Integer status = (Integer) attrs.get("status");
      if (status != null && status == 403) {
         httpServletRequest.setAttribute("unauthorized", true);
      }

      return "/app/login";
   }

   @Override
   public String getErrorPath() {
      return ERROR_PATH;
   }
}
```

So whenever an unauthorized attempt is made, this controller is hit and the condition of a status 403 triggers the logical branch in this method.  I added the request attribute "unauthorized" and forward to the login jsp page, to which I've added a section that detects the presence of the request attribute.  Voila, I'm all set.